# hibernate - while updating NonUniqueObjectException with pessimistic lock "upgrade"

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

hibernate 3.6.0 final

i have used pessimistic-lock

LockOptions  - because LockMode is not working i.e "select ... for update" "for update" is not generating in sql that's why.

at `session.saveOrUpdate` 
ERROR :

> org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException:
>   a different object with the same
>   identifier value was already
>   associated with the session:
>   [com.hermes.data.RateCode#RateCodeId{roomId=6836date=2011-02-01}

RateCode.hbm.xml

```
<class catalog="hermes" name="com.hermes.data.RateCode" table="ratecodes">
    <composite-id class="com.hermes.data.RateCodeId" name="id">
      <key-property name="roomId" type="int">
        <column name="roomId"/>
      </key-property>
      <key-property name="date" type="date">
        <column length="10" name="date" />
      </key-property>
    </composite-id>
```

java Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < roomId.length; i++) {
                existingRateCodeList = getRateCodeRoom(session, Integer.parseInt(roomId[i]), newRateCodeRange.getStartDate(), newRateCodeRange.getEndDate(), true, LockOptions.UPGRADE);
                updateRecord = existingRateCodeList.size();
                remainingRecord = totleRecord - updateRecord;

                if (existingRateCodeList.size() > 0) {
                    //update
                    updateOccured = true;
                    it = existingRateCodeList.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        existingRateCode = (RateCode) it.next();

                        updatedRecordList.add(existingRateCode.getId());
                        newRateCodeRange.setId(existingRateCode.getId());

                        session.saveOrUpdate(newRateCodeRange);
                        session.flush();
                        session.clear();
                    }
                    tx.commit();
                }
```

...............
getting list with the same session and/or another session.

with merge

> ERROR:
>   org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException:
>   Row was updated or deleted by another
>   transaction (or unsaved-value mapping
>   was incorrect):
>   [com.hermes.data.RateCode#RateCodeId{roomId=6836date=2011-02-01}

```
public List<RateCode> getRateCodeRoom(Session session, int roomId, Date from, Date to, boolean refreshCache, LockOptions lockOptions) {

        Query q = session.createQuery(
                "from RateCode rr where rr.id.roomId=:roomId and rr.id.date>=:from and rr.id.date<=:to order by rr.id.date").setInteger("roomId", roomId).setParameter("from", from).setParameter("to", to).setCacheable(true).setCacheMode(refreshCache ? CacheMode.REFRESH : CacheMode.NORMAL);

        if (lockOptions != null) {
            q.setLockOptions(lockOptions);
        }
        return q.list();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`saveOrUpdate` takes a detached instance (`newRateCodeRange`) and tries to attach it to the session. Its documentation says that an exception is thrown (the one you're encountering) if another instance of the same entity with the same ID is already associated with the session, which is the case here (`existingRateCode`).

You should probably use the `merge` method in order to copy the state of the detached instance to the attached one.

Comment: i tried with merge also but getting Error `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.hermes.data.RateCode#RateCodeId{roomId=6836date=2011-02-01}`

Comment: This exception means you're trying to save an entity with a version field that is obsolete compared to the one stored in thye database. The version of the entity you're trying to save is (for example) equals to 3, while the version in the database is 4 or 5, which means another transaction has made changes to the entity between the moment you loaded the entity and the moment you saved it. It might also mean you're trying to merge the same detached entity multiple times without refreshing its version field from the database.